# Chemistry project on hand warmers: Salt hydrates

Tags: physical-chemistry, applied-chemistry

Currently I am working on a chemistry project about hand warmers. My goal is to find a salt hydrate which gets warmer than sodium acetate trihydrate and can supercool. I already bought magnesium nitrate hexahydrate and aluminium ammonium sulfate dodecahydrate. I have tried to supercool them but they always crystallised so far.

Do you know if it is possible to supercool them? Can I mix two of the mentioned salt hydrates? For example, sodium acetate trihydrate and magnesium nitrate hexahydrate?

Comment: Have you tried pentahydrate of sodium thiosulfate ? It was used frequently in past as the main component of fixing solution in B/W photography. In my experience, it supercooled easily and was not too sensitive until seed was introduced.

Comment: And it makes spiffy crystals when viewed under crossed polarizers! https://www.travishale.com/sodium-thiosulfate-polarized-light-microscopy/ You might even include *your own* photos in your project